# Where to go from here with this Diophantine equation?

Tags: equation-solving

For the Collatz conjecture, this is my attempt to show that all numbers eventually go to 1 without encountering any loop besides the trivial, 1-4-2-1. We skip all multiples of 3 since those will be the `3x` values found by the (b==1 or b==2) conditions. The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic causes the comparison to `cat` to change to unity because all other categories will be altered by the -1 in the numerator and therefore never equal.

I assume that this reduction isn't proof, so I need some advice on what to do next. Perhaps some examples or links.

```
Clear[cat, b, c, m, n, o];
o = {Element[{cat, b, c, m, n}, Integers] && m >= 0 && n >= 0 && 
cat == 2 n + 1 && b == Mod[cat, 3] && (b == 0 && c == 0) ||
(((b == 1 && c == 4) || (b == 2 && c == 2)) && (c*cat*4^m - 1)/3 != cat)};
Reduce[o, {}, Integers]
```

Comment: [DiOphantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)

Comment: Better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am unable to figure out what is being asked here.